# Кроссбраузерный placeholder с использованием библиотеки Modernizr

Tags: jquery, html5

Делаю кроссбраузерный placeholder с использованием библиотеки [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) по книге К.Шмитта "HTML5. Рецепты программирования"

подключаю библиотеку к странице

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
```

пишу такой скрипт

```
    <script>
    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
          $(".search_form_field").focus(function() {
            if ($(".search_form_field").val() == $(".search_form_field").attr('placeholder')) {
              $(".search_form_field").val("");
            }
          });
          $(".search_form_field").blur(function() {
            if ($(".search_form_field").val() == "") {
              $(".search_form_field").val($(".search_form_field").attr('placeholder'));
            }
          });
        $(".search_form_field").blur();
        $(".search").submit(function() {
          if ($(".search_form_field").val() ==
        $(".search_form_field").attr('placeholder')) {
          return false;
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

но в ие он все равно не срабатывает.
В чем может быть проблема? Делаю вот для такой [верстки](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index9/index.html), для формы ввода логина и пароля.

Comment: @Heidel Всё в подробностях расписал (и как с библиотекой modernizr и как без неё), но автор молчит...:)

Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @romeo извините, несколько забегалась, некогда посмотреть) и тут столько ответов разных дали, хочется все смотреть, разбираться)

Comment: @Heidel Отпишитесь о результате. Мне интересно, а то у меня лишь IE6 и IE10 установлена.

Если не получится, то тогда уж используйте jquery.placeholder.min.js. Можно просто в header-е "подцепить" без modernizr.

ИМХО: Если у Вас в проекте накопиться достаточно много html 5 фишек, таких как: placeholder, css3, pushState..., то modernizr вполне оправдан.

Comment: @Heidel Исправил. Теперь работает и в 9-ке (IE6-10).
Заменил

   this.placeholder;

на

   this.getAttribute('placeholder');

Comment: @romeo. да, работает. большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используйте библиотеку modernizr для только лишь кроссбраузерного placeholder-а, то это сильно накладно.

Пользоваться ей просто:
Подбираете конструктором необходимою для Вас конфигурацию и скачивайте:

[Modernizr Download Builder](http://modernizr.com/download/)

Примечание: под катом "**Non-core detects**" выбираете "**forms-placeholder**".

Далее полученный файл подключаете в head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.js"></script>
```

И, собственно, загрузчик:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.input.placeholder,
    nope: '/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js',
    complete : function () {
      if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('#search').placeholder();
      }
    }
});
```

, где **nope** - абсолютный путь  к плагину; **complete** - как только всё вышеобъявленное загрузиться/выполнится.

Кстати, неплохая подборка плагинов (Polyfills), рекомендованная разработчиком Modernizr:

[HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)

, а также:

[Modernizr: практическое применение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144352/)

---

Привожу своё решение, которое использую в проектах.

```
$.fn.textPlaceholder = function () {

    /**
     *  Используем для тех браузеров,
     *  которые не поддерживают  атрибут "placeholder"
     */ 
    if (
        this.length && 
        'placeholder' in document.createElement(this[0].tagName)
    ) return;

    var that = this,
        input = $(this);

     /* По умолчанию при загрузке скрипта */    
    input.val(
        function() {
            return (!this.value) ? this.getAttribute('placeholder') : this.value;
        }
    );

    input.blur(function() {
        if (!this.value) this.value = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
    }).focus(function() {
        if (this.value == this.getAttribute('placeholder')) this.value = '';
    });

    /**
     *  Если input-ы пусты, то отправляем (сабмитим) на сервер пустые данные,
     *  а не содержимое placeholder
     */  
    input.parents('form').submit(function(){
        $(that).val(function() {
             if (this.value == this.getAttribute('placeholder')) return '';
             return this.value;
        });
    });
};
```

Подключение:

```
$('#search').textPlaceholder();
```

Пример вёрстки:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Искать на сайте...">
```

P.S. Валидно и для IE6.

P.P.S. Можно мой пример скрипта провести через тот же Modernizr.

```
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
    $('#search').textPlaceholder();
}
```

, тогда указанное в примере условие поддержки браузерами атрибута "placeholder" можно опустить.

Comment: спасибо за предложенные варианты!  
а что это за скрипт nope: '/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js' ? откуда его надо взять?

Comment: а, всё, понятно. сделала по первому варианту, так как хотелось всё- таки библиотеку Modernizr попробовать использовать. не могу разобраться, на локально сервере в ие всё работает и отображается без проблем, а если верстку куда-то загрузить, то появляется такая ошибка http://i.imgur.com/eL29G.png и скрипт не срабатывает. неправильно приписаны пути или в чем причина?

Comment: @Heidel Я указал ссылку на подборку от разработчика Modernizr. Там представлено несколько плагинов для placeholder-а:[HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)Вот прямая ссылка:[jquery.placeholder.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)Представленные варианты от других тех. специалистов, не учитывали нюансы, к примеру с сабмитом, а так по сути, одинаковые.

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на мой последний комментарий:> Только в исходном виде (не min) он> занимает прилично:> > [jquery.placeholder.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js)По сути, мой представленный вариант занимает гораздо меньше строк кода и по функциональности нареканий нет. Так что, смотрите сами. Впрочем, modernizr тоже можно не использовать. Аналогичная проверка кроссбразерности в моём примере есть.И да, та хабра-статья по modernizr, ссылку на которою я указал в ответе, исчерпывающая.

Comment: @Heidel
> то появляется такая ошибка http://i.imgur.com/eL29G.png и скрипт 

Лучше абсолютные прописать.

Comment: @romeo у меня почему-то ваш скрипт - тот, что без использования библиотеки, - в ие7 и ие8 работает, а в ие9 - нет. это как-то можно подкрутить, чтобы он и там работал?

Comment: @Heidel Уфф... в погоне за оптимизацией вот такой вот неприятный результат (пока отвечал старался оптимизировать глядя, на представленные ответы ниже).
Зайдите в историю изменений моего ответа на Ваш вопрос, а именно:

http://hashcode.ru/revisions/181398/

Попробуйте сперва 12, а потом 3.

Answer (score 2):

Есть же [**jQuery.placeholder**](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder)!

Comment: Плагин не скачать.

Comment: Нашел на [github](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder). Правда, не уверен, что это именно тот самый.

Comment: @Deonis Тот самый. Только в исходном виде (не min) он занимает прилично:[jquery.placeholder.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js)Кстати, неплохая подборка плагинов от разработчика Modernizr:[HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)

Answer (score 1):

В обоих примерах мегатонны кода. Зачем?!

```
<input 
    value="Логин..." 
    onblur='if(this.value=="") `this.value="Логин...";'
    onfocus='if(this.value=="Логин...") this.value = "";' 
    type="text"
>
```

2:

```
$('input[placeholder!=""]').each(function() {
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(!this.value) this.value=this.getAttribute('placeholder');
    }).focus(function() {
        if(this.value==this.getAttribute('placeholder')) this.value = "";
    });
});
```

Comment: @lampa Да, Вы правы, было много мусора + немного не оптимизировано, ибо давность данного скрипта не сопоставима с нынешним опытом - руки не доходили переделать. Подправил, как видите.

Ваш вариант не учитывает сабмит, ибо на сервер в случае, если input-ы пусты, отправится содержимое атрибута "placeholder" + ни к чему использовать данный скрипт, если браузер имеет нативную поддержку последнего.

Comment: @romeo я на сервере проверяю, т.к. в общем виде всё равно получается меньше кода. (проверяю на сервере простой регуляркой, которая смотрит наличие неЛатинских символов).

Comment: Код @lampa тоже можно немного сократить: **each()** - не нужен.

    $('input[placeholder!=""]').blur(function() {
        if(!this.value) this.value=this.getAttribute('placeholder');
    }).focus(function() {
        if(this.value==this.getAttribute('placeholder')) this.value = "";
    });

Comment: @Deonis ступил)

Comment: @lampa Аналогично, опустил each:)
Повторюсь, без сабмита никак (так более универсально, нежели некая проверка на стороне сервера через "регикс"). Кроме того, необходимо при загрузке страницы по умолчанию задать value, а не только по событию blur/focus.

Comment: тут замещающий текст в инпуте будет отображаться только при клике на поле ввода.